# How to locate an object in EF Diagram

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4

I have a rather large and complex EF entity. I pulled in a couple of views I don't want to include. Finding them in the LARGE diagram is a real pill. Is that the only place I can delete them? If so, is there a trick (ctl-f doesn't work...) to find an entity quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Open Model Browser window and it will allow you [searching for the entity](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2010/07/05/search-for-an-entity-in-your-entity-data-model.aspx).